# How to add string ( ' ) in array value on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have string value of input type=hidden like this:

```
A,B,C
```

then i convert that string to array with .split()in javascript:

`var menu = $('#title_list').val(); 
 var arrayMenu = menu.split(",");`

and the results:

```
arrayMenu = ["A","B","C"]
```

If i want to make that array value to be like this:

```
arrayMenu = ["'A'","'B'","'C'"]
```

how to do it?

Comment: you cant, however you can run a forEach on the resulting array and then mutate it to wrap it in `'`

Answer (score 1):

You can just map the values of the array. Assuming you have the following:

```js
let arrayMenu = ['A', 'B', 'C']
arrayMenu = arrayMenu.map((item) => `'${item}'`);
console.log(arrayMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could almost certainly use a regular expression, but a reasonably straightforward way could be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayMenu.length; i++) {
   arrayMenu[i] = "'" + arrayMenu[i] + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayMenu = ["A","B","C"];

const newArray = arrayMenu.map(arr => `'${arr}'`);

console.log(arrayMenu, newArray);


// Another Solution
arrayMenu.forEach((currentValue, index) => arrayMenu[index] = `'${currentValue}'`);

console.log(arrayMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayMenu.forEach((v, i) => arrayMenu[i] = "'"+v+"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

While string value of input type=hidden is `A,B,C` <sup>Personally</sup> I'll try to shape the string then make the array instead of make the array then do a foreach loop again

```js
var menu = $('#title_list').val();
var arrayMenu = ("'"+ menu +"'").replace(/,/g , "','").split(",");
console.log(arrayMenu);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="title_list" value="A,B,C" />
```

Explanation for `("'"+InputValue +"'").replace(/,/g , "','").split(",");`:

- `("'"+menu+"'")` Add single quote outside the value to be `'A,B,C'`
- `.replace(/,/g , "','")` replace the comma with `','` to be `'A' , 'B' , 'C'`
- `.split(",")` to split by comma to make the array

Comment: I've tried using this code and its works too, thank you for the explanation!